# JS: Forward to a site with random parts in the URL

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, redirect, random

by opening a HTML-site, I want to redirect to the following page:

www.xyz.de?user=default&f1=**OPTION1**&f2=**OPTION2**&f3=**OPTION3**&f4=**OPTION4**&f5=**OPTION5**&... etc.

The value for the "OPTIONS" should be randomly selected from a list (array) for every OPTION (1,2,3,4,5,..).

How can I do this with Javascript?

kind regards

Comment: is the problem to redirect or to generate the string?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you, you didn't provide much details or a demo code, so this is from my point of understanding only.

```
<p id="Link">Link Here</p>
<p id="randoms">Randomly Sortde Array</p>
<script>
var options = ["OPTION1", "OPTION2", "OPTION3", "OPTION4", "OPTION5"]; // Our main array of options
options.sort(function(a, b){return 0.5 - Math.random()}); // We reorder the elements randomly, using : function(a, b){return 1 - Math.random()} will give us the reversed array.
document.getElementById("randoms").innerHTML = options; // Our "randmoly" sorted array
document.getElementById("Link").innerHTML = "www.xyz.de/?user=default&f1="+options[0]+"&f2="+options[1]+"&f3="+options[2]+"&f4="+options[3]+"&f5="+options[4]; // Our Final Link
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it:

```
<script>
var fn = ["Wolfgang", "Sven", "Michael", "Heike", "Güldane", "Olga", "Torben", "Steffi", "Hubert"];
ZFN = Math.random()*8;
ZFN = Math.round( ZFN );
document.getElementById("FN").innerHTML = fn[ZFN];
var ln = ["Gley", "Fröbel", "Robering", "Kreinsberger", "Arslan-Storch", "Walter", "Piwitt", "Reger", "Köferl"];
ZLN = Math.random()*8;
ZLN = Math.round( ZLN );
document.getElementById("LN").innerHTML = ln[ZLN];
var bt = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28"];
ZBT = Math.random()*28;
ZBT = Math.round( ZBT );
document.getElementById("BT").innerHTML = bt[ZBT];
var bm = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
ZBM = Math.random()*11;
ZBM = Math.round( ZBM );
document.getElementById("BM").innerHTML = bm[ZBM];
var bj = ["1980", "1982", "1987", "1972", "1973", "1966", "1994", "1999", "1989", "1991", "1992", "1993"];
ZBJ = Math.random()*11;
ZBJ = Math.round( ZBJ );
document.getElementById("BJ").innerHTML = bj[ZBJ];
var id1 = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
ID1 = Math.random()*9;
ID1 = Math.round( ID1 );
document.getElementById("ID1").innerHTML = id1[ID1];
var id2 = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
ID2 = Math.random()*9;
ID2 = Math.round( ID2 );
document.getElementById("ID2").innerHTML = id2[ID2];
var id3 = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
ID3 = Math.random()*9;
ID3 = Math.round( ID3 );
document.getElementById("ID3").innerHTML = id3[ID3];
var id4 = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
ID4 = Math.random()*9;
ID4 = Math.round( ID4 );
document.getElementById("ID4").innerHTML = id4[ID4];
var id5 = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
ID5 = Math.random()*9;
ID5 = Math.round( ID5 );
document.getElementById("ID5").innerHTML = id5[ID5];
var seite=fn;
window.location ="http://XYZ:8082/target?user=admin&fn=" + fn[ZFN] + "&ln=" + ln[ZLN] + "&bd=" + bt[ZBT] + bm[ZBM] + bj[ZBJ]  + "&id=" +  id1[ID1] + id2[ID2] + id3[ID3] + id4[ID4] + id5[ID5]
</script>
```

**THANKS TO ALL!!**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide more information, like what it does? It seems like hardcoded